# QlikView licencing and is QlikView server necessary?

Tags: qlikview

I have a requirement where I need to inform some clients regarding QlikView licenses.

I also wanted to know if QlikView server is mandatory?

I found this link: 
http://www.covaligroup.com/Qlikview-Euro-Pricing/

Any information is welcome.

Comment: Just contact your local Qlik partner for a quote

Comment: @StefanStoichev : thanks and can we do adhoc analysis in Qlikview,like user could create their own report in qlikview server? like in tableau users could do their own reports using data aources available is the same possible in QLikview server? thanks!

Comment: I'll say "yes". But it need more clarification. I don't know how is in Tableau that's why i cant compare.

Comment: @Chio yeah, adhoc reporting can be done inside a qlikview model with the data that it has available to users. Would have to check on the specific Tableau capabilities, but the short (and comercial) answer is yes

Answer (score 1):

so the first answer is: Contact a local QlikView distribution channel and they will guide you through their licencing processes.

Nevertheless, you have a web page such as:

http://www.qlik.com/legal/license-terms

that shows the exact limitations and capabilities of each of their licences.

Finally, if you want to distribute the models or reports you create using QlikView, the Server is mandatory, since QlikView files cannot be opened in a different computer than the one they were created in, **except of course if you are leasing a license from a server, and your QV is no longer flagged as "personal edition"**

c ya around

Comment: "qlikview files cannot be opened in a different computer than the one they were created in" is incorrect.  QVW files can be opened in QlikView Desktop by any licensed user, that is using any license other than Personal Edition.

Comment: That is indeed correct, ( I mean your correction) corrected by one of the big ones, don't know what happened there... Will edit and add your correction there @RobWunderlich

Answer (score 1):

Qlik has the Qlikview Desktop Personal Edition for developers or business analyst that uses it for personal information.
When is needed share these information, is necessary use Qlikview server with licensed users.

Answer (score 0):

Qlikview server is necessary if you're looking to host your documents on the "Web portal" type interface for clients to access.

I think it also costs about £200.00 per licence, depending on your company size.

Answer (score 0):

Qlikview has two version for developer

1) Desktop +ve side is its free but you cannot share 
(http://www.qlik.com/us/explore/products/qlikview/free-download-from-here) 
2) developer + side you can share with other licence holder however cost will be $1350 per named user. (depends on your agreement with Qlik)

Also note you need to get a reader licence for all user who need to access the file, Sorry cannot help you with cost

Now server is for Hosting and providing a multi user access to your file(QVW). Same can be used to share file across different Platform and device and region . Server most often include Developer licence its addition to Server cost.

Note server doesn't include Publisher or any other tool. Hope that help

More details can
 be found on http://qlik.com

Answer (score 0):

Qlik is expensive when it comes to servers and such so make sure to find a distributor like 'Differentia' so you can cut costs on Licenses.

You will need UserCals & DocCals for sharing.